# Cannot load sibling route component in lazy load module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

I cannot seem to load a sibling route from a lazy loaded feature. The first component loads - PlayListsComponent. But I cannot navigate from there to the sibling route - playlist/:id. I believe it has something to do with the 'path'.

I tried using the relative path option when calling navigate from the already loaded component.

```
const ROUTES = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: PlayListsComponent,
    resolve: {data: PlayListsResolverService},
  },
  {
    path: 'playlist/:id',
    component: PlayListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'playlist-add/:id',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: '../playlist-edit/playlist-edit.module#PlaylistEditModule'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PlayListsComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES),
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [PlayListsResolverService]
})
export class PlaylistViewModule {}
```

This was how I call the navigate method. Perhaps ['playlist'] is not the correct path...

```
  handlePlaylist(pl) {
    this.playlistService.setCurrentPlaylist(pl);
    this.router.navigate(['playlist', pl.playlist_id, {
      snapshotId: pl.snapshot_id,
      totalTracks: pl.tracks.total,
      playlistName: pl.name
    }, {relative: this.route}]);
  }
```

Now I can see the router grabs the correct url, appends the id but can't match, so the wild card default component gets called, which is a login component in the main module routing config.

[image: console.error]

I expect the playlist/:id component to load.

What am I missing? Is this the correct set up? cheers!

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: no error, just jumps to the default component.

Comment: Finally now I get a noMatchError  **Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'playlist;...*** if I change the route to **/playlist**

Answer (score 0):

So referencing the relative route is the issue here.

```
handlePlaylist(pl) {
    this.playlistService.setCurrentPlaylist(pl);
    this.router.navigate(['playlist',{
      snapshotId: pl.snapshot_id,
      id: pl.playlist_id,
      totalTracks: pl.tracks.total,
      playlistName: pl.name
    }], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```